# Why is isNULL returning empty string in vbScript w/ Parameterized Query

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic

I am connecting to a database with this query -

myCMD.commandtext =  "select  customer_reviews.meta_title, customer_reviews.meta_description from customer_reviews inner join customers on customer_reviews.customer_id = customers.id where customers.id = ? limit 1" 
myCMD.Parameters.Append myCMD.CreateParameter("@customerID", adInteger, adParamInput, 10, request("customer"))
set myRS = myCMD.execute

I then have this code:

if Not isNULL(myRS("meta_title")) or myRS("meta_title") <> ""  Then
page_meta_title = myRS("meta_title")
end if

if Not isNULL(myRS("meta_description")) or myRS("meta_description") <> ""  Then
page_meta_description = myRS("meta_description")
end if

Both fields have a string value. The parameter page_meta_title was populating fine, but page_meta_description was always returning an empty string - when I know it was not empty.

After looking at the database, I noticed that the first field was of type varChar with the second was of Text. I changed the Text datatype to varchar and it worked, returning a value to the parameter.

If my debugging is correct, does a field of type Text not work with isNULL?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to write the variable page_meta_title and not parameter

Answer (score 0):

It turned out when if I first added this -

```
myMetaTitle = myRS("meta_title").value
myMetaDescription = myRS("meta_description").value
myKeywords = myRS("meta_keywords").value
```

Then ran my conditional statements it worked regardless of varchar or text field